# Passing data from Server in C language to a python script

Tags: sockets, network-programming, cgi, server

I am developing a prototype web application. I am using a toy http server which I have developed myself and it is written in C. The server needs to obtain text data from html form submitted and for furthur processing should pass it to a script which I have written in python. I know the following methods to achieve the same. Also once the processing is done the script has to return the data to server.

1. Save the data in a file and let the python script access it.
2. Calling the system or exec family of functions from within the Server code.
3. I have heard of CGI where a socket is used on both sides. I know how to do the same in my python script. But I am not able to see how the same is done in C server side.

Normally this is abstracted out as most people use apache or nginx as theor service. How can CGI be achieved in Server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI is covered here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875

By 'CGI over sockets' you probably mean *FastCGI* which is a bit different (and involves a long running process listening on a Unix socket and sending back responses). Classical CGI involves spawning a short lived process which then receives the request parameters via environment variables (set this from your server via `setenv()`.

Request data is sent to the spawned process via *stdin* (e.g. in Python, `sys.stdin`). The output response is then written (with headers and all) via stdout.

CGI is very simple and this is why it was so quick to be adopted by a high number of languages -- the learning curve to implementing CGI was rather quick.

FastCGI is similar to CGI only at the script language layer (i.e. the programming interface remains somewhat similar); however the actual mechanics are rather different (you need to serialize the information over Unix sockets).